# PhantomJS and Karma, Selector [ng\:model="query.name"] did not match any elements

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, karma-runner

When executing a karma runner using the PhantomJS browser the following error is produced:

```
*Selector [ng\:model="query.name"] did not match any elements*.
```

When executing with Chrome everything is working as expected.
Here's the line that should be matched:

```
`<input size='' style='width:3em;' ng-model="query.name"  ng-change=changeQuery() ng-focus=focus($index) ng-blur=loseFocus($index)>`
```

**karma.conf:**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

    basePath: '../..',

    frameworks: ['ng-scenario'],

    plugins : [
        'karma-ng-scenario',
        'karma-chrome-launcher',
        'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
        'karma-junit-reporter'
    ],

    files: [
        'test/webapp/app/e2e/*.js'
    ],

    exclude: [

    ],

    proxies : {
        '/': 'http://localhost:19880'
    },

    reporters: ['progress', 'junit'],

    port: 9876,

    colors: true,

    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    autoWatch: false,

    browsers: [ 'Chrome', 'PhantomJS'],

    captureTimeout: 60000,

    singleRun: false
});
```

- NodeJS version: **v0.10.17**
- Karma version: **0.10.2**
- PhantomJS version: **1.9**

Comment: you're looking up the element `ng:model` but the code is `ng-model`. I don't know the context and i'm just guessing, though

Comment: I am having this same issue.  Eduard logical guess, but that is just how angular scenario outputs it.

Comment: Oops - mine is NOT working in CHROME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the failure was that the PhantomJS is built with an old version of JavaScript that is missing the *"bind"* implementation ([Why PhantomJS doesn't have Function.prototype.bind](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phantomjs/r0hPOmnCUpc/uxusqsl2LNoJ))

The controller logic was using *currying*, with the bind method, and thus caused the page render incorrectly. I found this out when exporting a rendered page with the phantomJS browser.

I removed all the *bind method calls* from the controller code and End2end test(s) are now passing as as expected.

I apologize that from the information that I have provided for the issue, it is impossible to deduct the problem cause.